# Export Version and Adapters from the Source Code using the mfpdev (Exporting Zips from Adapter and Source Code)

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-cli

Hi we are planning to have a automated build for our IBM Mobilefirst cordova project. we are now using the mfpdev to deploy the adapter and also to register the new version using the CLI via Azure dev ops. But some of our MFP Server's are not accessible to the outside so for us the only way is to go the mfpconsole export the Adapter and Version and manually install them in those machines. Is there any command to export the Adapter.zip and version.zip from our source code via mfpdev so that i can store them in our build process and we wont loose older adapters in the process.

The only thing i can see it `mfpdev app export` which help me export the entire application which i don't need.

Answer (score 1):

Mfpdev CLI does not have such an option. However, you can either use mfpadm command line tool or Admin REST endpoint to achieve this:

1. mfpadm command:

   [Adapter get binary](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/it/foundation/8.0/administering-apps/using-cli/#commands-for-adapters)

   Usage:

   `mfpadm adapter mfp <Adapter_Name> get binary > /tmp/MyAdapter.adapter`
2. Export resources using Admin REST API:

   [Download Resources](http://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/api-ref/rest-admin-api-docs/html/refrest-admin-service-api-docs/html/r_restapi_export_resources_get.html). With this option, you can export adapter binaries.

   Usage:

   `https://www.example.com/mfpadmin/management-apis/2.0/runtimes/myruntime/export?resourceInfos=<Adapter_Name>||ADAPTER_CONTENT`

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply but still even in here what we are doing is exporting the adapter or version from the mobilefirst server via a Cli / REST API instead of the Mfp Console but what i wanted was to get the same from the source code not the server.

Comment: From the source code you can build and deploy. What you ask seem to be about copying it over. This is not possible with mfpdev.